# How to use manipulate in julia

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I have a problem with the interactive plots.

```
using Interact, Vega, Distributions
@manipulate for μ in -10:10, σ = 0.1:0.5:5.1
    x = -20:0.01:20
    lineplot(y = pdf(Normal(μ, σ), x), x=x)
end
```

This is my result, isn't the widget for manipulate de parameters:

[image: This is my result, isn't the widget for manipulate de parameters]

Comment: Do I need install any pkg for the widget?

Comment: you have a typo: `…for μ=-10:10…`